# Validity of TransferWise Borderless account statements for visa applications?

Tags: visas, money

I'm a British citizen, living in Mexico, working remotely for a US company.  I get paid in USD, and I like to save money in both USD and GBP while also having local Mexican currency to spend.  For that reason I use a Borderless account from TransferWise.
It comes with US bank details, which allows my employer to make deposits in dollars.  I can then convert some of the money to Mexican pesos to spend locally using the TransferWise debit card, and send some of it in British pounds to my HSBC bank account back in the UK.

I can export PDF statements from the TransferWise website for any of the currencies which I hold.  For instance, I can export a statement showing my monthly gross income deposited in USD by my employer.  The statements feature the contact details for TransferWise, my verified address in the UK, and other data relating to TransferWise's authorisation under the Electronic Money Regulations 2011.

Would these statements be sufficient to prove my income for a Mexican visa application for myself, or a UK visa application for my Mexican partner in the future?
I ask only because they are not issued by a traditional bank like HSBC, but a more modern electronic money institution.

Comment: I assume you're applying for a long-term Mexican visa?

Comment: Short-term residency.

Comment: Did it work in the end? Did they accept TransferWise reports?

Answer (score 1):

While I can't readily find the same information for Mexico (perhaps because it'd be in Spanish) the answer to these questions is always the same: there's no mechanical formula. You need to convince the officer handling your case you have the means to support yourself on a trip and the ties to return. You send in documents supporting these claims. Canada actually posts "policy, procedures and guidance used by Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada staff" and the relevant [page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/proof-funds-financial-support.html) has this:

> To assess the adequacy of a visitor's financial resources, you may exercise discretion in the documentation you request from applicants.

Somewhat obviously you can't expect regulation to keep up with all these companies, Transferwise, Revolut, whatnot. So I'd expect them to accept it as long as the story is consistent: you have a contract with the employer and regular income. As for faking such statements, no difference really, it's not like an embassy can just ask a bank whether the submitted statements are valid. Bank secrecy laws are very strict everywhere.

Once again: if your story as presented is solid, you are good to go.